# Macbook pro freezing after clean install

Tags: performance, console

My Macbook Pro (2015, Catalina) begun to freeze when I logged on to my main user account a couple of days ago. After the loading screen I approximately 2-5 seconds passed before everything froze, including the cursor. The spinning wheel didn't even appear, only a complete freeze. The laptop also didn't go to sleep if closed in this state.

I tried the following without luck:

- SMC- and Pram reset
- Disc Utility, shows no errors.
- List of log-in items on user account wiped clean.
- csstore files removed, as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305097/macbook-pro-stuck-after-i-enter-my-password?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- clean install of Catalina via USB boot drive incl. erasing disk.

But alas, the issue persists. Since the clean install I've tried:

- fsck from Single User Mode. Results in `/dev/rdisk1 is mounted with write access`.
- disabling System Integrity Protection
- running verification via Terminal diskutil with no issues (same goes for repair).
- Apple Hardware Test - no warnings except for the usual 'replace battery soon' message

In safe mode, this is posted to the console every 5 seconds. 
Any idea what it means?

> AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[465]: Failed to register for device
>   notification events and start runloop
>   AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[465]:
>   Failed to initialize MobileRestore, can't perform registration right
>   now.
>   AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[465]: Failed to create mux listener

Comment: [Catalina: Login Screen Freezes After Password Entry](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378324/catalina-login-screen-freezes-after-password-entry) ... [Macbook Pro stuck after I enter my password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305097/macbook-pro-stuck-after-i-enter-my-password?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Try booting in Safe Mode.  Also, try installing a previous version of macOS to the USB drive and boot from that.

Comment: did going back level OS fix the problem?

Comment: NVRAM reset helped me with this issue on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6