# How to debug the user login process

Tags: catalina, user-account, login, logs

After the Catalina update I can't login with my main user any more. Mostly all I get is the turning wheel but once I got Welcome message notification and clicking that started Safari. And from the Apple menu I was able the system settings and the app store.

I also have a few secondary users and I can login to those just fine. Which is different to the [very](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250806737) [many](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117459) reports of user who where logged out after the Catalina update. Some where the user was left with [deleting the hard drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378324/catalina-login-screen-freezes-after-password-entry) to solve the problem.

Since I still have one working admin user I hope that I'm spared that fate. It seemed that the update itself was successful and the OS itself is still in working order.

I can also login to the damaged user via `su`.

What I want to know is: Is there a way to debug the login process to see where the login hangs?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning out the `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory worked for me.

See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251132653

I'll find out later which of the auto start applications fail to load.